# Startactivity for result, returns in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, landscape, portrait

I'm starting the camera via:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

It works without any errors. The only problem is when im returning, the layout is in **Landscape** mode eventhough im holding in portrait. Im able to get the image data here.

The screen returns to portrait-mode automatically after a short while, but then the data is lost.

Setting orientation in manifest does no effect.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.camera"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.camera.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Do you have any tips on how to return from camera to mainactivity in portrait?

Comment: tried this in your activity?    android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: yes I have! Still returns in landscape and a short while after rotates back to portrait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<activity
android:name="path.youractivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

I have confusion about your `Activity` orientation so if you want to go with `portrait` then set the `screenOrientation` as **portrait** and for `landscape` set **landscape**

Try this way to setting the fixed orientation

I have updated I think it just because of screen size changed during orientation of activities. This was more affected from 4.0 I think so, Add this `screensize` in orientation and then test it

Comment: You mean screeOrientation="portrait" ?
I have done this and it still returns in landscape

Comment: Hmm, It still returns in landscape and changes orientation, but the data is kept! And im able to get the data!

Answer (score 0):

try making your camera open in portrait mode with this

```
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Did no effect. I think the camera view is locked in landscape